# Password protect individual Android apps

Tags: android, security

I am looking for an extremely secure Android app to password protect individual apps, such as banking.

Money is no object, only security matters.

Ideally, something that will let me use fingerprint, face or PIN. E.g use face, but it won't work in low light, so use one of the others, but some devices won't have fingerprint, or I may be wearing gloves in winter, so use one of the others. Preferably, not just "choose one of these 3, and you are stuck with it", but use any 1 of these 3 each time you use the app.

But, again, only security matters.

Comment: Under pressure? Provocation? OK, my usual comment: you are looking for an [App-Locker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_applocker)?

Comment: I am trying out [LockIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ushareit.lockit&hl=en_GB&gl=US) which seems to work ok, but might need more testing